# How to map to controls into an NES emulator with Lua?

Tags: lua, output, emulation

I'm attempting to do something similar to what [Mari/o](http://pastebin.com/ZZmSNaHX) does, but with different AI principles and techniques.

However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to actually send input from the Lua script to the emulator (for example, up down left right a b etc).

I'm trying to figure out how the guy who wrote Mari/o did it in his script, but I'm scratching my head trying to figure out how it works.

So, can someone please explain to me how mapping input to an NES emulator works?

Code so far..(this is using the FCEUX emulator)

```
inputTable = joypad.read(1);

for k, v in pairs (inputTable) do
  if(k == "right") then
    v = true;
  end;
  print(k, v);
end;

while (true) do
  joypad.set(1, inputTable);
  joypad.write(1, inputTable);
  emu.frameadvance();

end;
```

However, I don't think that joypad.set or joypad.write are correct for setting input, because they don't seem to do anything other than overwrite player input.

Comment: You aren't assigning into `inputTable` anywhere. You are assigning to the local `v` variable. You want to assign to `inputTable[k]` instead.

Comment: ......you're right. Now it works....gah now I feel dumb. Thank you for pointing that out. I thought that v was just a pointer to that spot in inputTable.

Comment: Don't edit your question with your solution. That just invalidates the question.

Comment: Ah sorry I'll edit it back. I see you did that. Thanks

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, I've had people only post answers in comments before and not as a submission. I jumped to conclusions, my apologies.

Comment: I've been guilty on more than one occasion of leaving a comment-only answer for something that I didn't think warranted a full answer (usually because I think there's a high probability it is duplicate or too narrow) but in that situation I'd say it would be better to file an answer based on the comment (you can mark it community wiki if you don't want to claim ownership) but that way at least the normal mode of operation is retained (and your question stands less chance of being flagged/closed I would imagine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't actually assigning into `inputTable at any point here.

The variable `v` is a local in the `for` loop. It isn't a pointer/reference/etc. to the value in the table.

To assign to the table you need to actually assign to `inputTable[k]` in the loop.